# How to compose a matrix to perform isometric (dimetric) projection of a world coordinate?

Tags: opengl, c++, matrix

I have a 2D unit vector containing a world coordinate (the player's direction), and I want to convert that to screen coordinates (classic isometric tiles).

I'm aware I can achieve this by [rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6510027/17540) around the relevant axis but I want to see and understand how to do this using a purely matrix approach? Partly because I'm learning 'modern OpenGL' (v2+) and partly because I will want to use this same technique for other things so need a solid understanding and my math ability is a little lacking.

If needed my screen's coordinate system has it's origin at top left with +x & +y pointing right and down respectively. Also, my vertex positions are converted to the NDC range in my vertex shader if that's relevant.

Language is C++ with no supporting libraries.

Comment: By 'purely matrix' I mean, I think I should be able to do this by: `Mat4 p = { /*some magic numbers*/ }; Vector2 v = direction * p;`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just use the standard projection * view * direction method

Comment: A standard isometric world-to-screen matrix (considering in pixels) would be like [[cos 330, cos 210], [sin 330, sin 210]]

Comment: [You might find this answer useful in this direction](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132592/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory thanks, I've done quite a bit of searching and reading across the stack exchange sites.